# Solving $\frac{x+y}{z}=\frac{y+z}{x}=\frac{z+x}{y}=k$ for $k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> For how many different real values of $k$ do there exist real numbers $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that
>   $$\frac{x+y}{z}=\frac{y+z}{x}=\frac{z+x}{y}=k?$$

I solved this as this: Take the second ratio:
$$\frac{y}{x}+\frac{z}{x}=k \Longrightarrow \frac{z}{x}=k-\frac{y}{x}=\frac{xk-y}{x} \Longrightarrow z=xk-y.$$
Substitute $z$ in the first ratio:
$$\frac{x+y}{(xk-y}=k \Longrightarrow y=x(k-1).$$
Again, substitute this y to find $z$:
$$z=xk-x(k-1) \Longrightarrow z=x.$$
Now, the third ratio  will be
$$\frac{x+x}{x(k-1)}=k \Longrightarrow k^2-k-2=0 \Longrightarrow k=-1,2.$$
Is this solution correct?

Comment: Please use MathJax to edit your question. You will receive answers more quickly that way.

Comment: @Allawonder ...   I tried using MathJax to input this question, but MathJax is not working on my PC (for some reason!).

Comment: No problem now. Someone has done it for you already. It's now readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a different approach.

We can rewrite the system as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-k & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -k & 1 \\
1 & 1 & -k \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{pmatrix} = 0,
$$
with the conditions $x,y,z\neq0$.

In order to have a solution, $0$ must be an eigenvalue. But the eigenvalues of the matrix are $-1-k$ an $2-k$, therefore $k$ must be either $-1$ or $2$. In either case, we can exhibit a corresponding vector in the kernel with nonzero entries, namely $(1,1,-2)$ and $(1,1,1)$, so both solutions are admissible.

Comment: Thank you @Federico ...  also ... I wanted to confirm that only one real value of k exists, where the ratios hold true, ya? ... because k=-1, is not a real number, it is an integer. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

$k=2$ because:

$2(x+y+z)=k(x+y+z)$

$(k-2)(x+y+z)=0$

⇒$k-2=0 ⇒ k=2$

Or: $x+y+z=0$

in this case k could be any number if x, y, z are integers.

This comes out when you do operations for three fractions and sum LHS of resulted relation , also RHS of relations.

Comment: $k=-1$ is also correct, since you can have $x+y+z=0$ with all three variables non-zero.

Comment: Thank You @sirous ...   I wanted to confirm that only one real value of k exists, where the ratios hold true, ya? ...   because k=-1, is not a real number, it is an integer.   Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

You get the right answer. I just have an observation: in the equation after "Substitute $z$ ..."
$$\frac{x+y}{xk-y}=k$$
You rewrite this as $y=x(k-1)$. That is true only if $k\ne-1$. This would yield $x+y+z=0$ when $x,y,z\ne 0$

Comment: Thanks @Andrei ...   Please explain why y=x(k-1) is true only when k=-1 ...   Thanks again.

Comment: I should have said that $y=x(k-1)$ is only one of the solutions, which corresponds to the case where $k\ne -1$. If $k=-1$ the equation is valid for any $x,y$ pair if $x+y\ne 0$. In this case you have $\frac{x+y}{-x-y}=-1$ (always true)

Comment: I am slightly confused now. ...   y=x(k-1) is a solution when k is equal to -1 or when k is not equal to -1. ...

Comment: also  ... I wanted to confirm that only one real value of k exists, where the ratios hold true, ya? ... because k=-1, is not a real number, it is an integer. Am I correct?

Comment: -1 is as real as 2. When $k=-1$ it is not necessary to have $y=x(k-1)$ to verify the first equation